# Mean and variance of a general multivariate skew normal distribution

Tags: st.statistics, probability-distributions, integration

I have a problem about a general multivariate skew normal distribution. There is a $p\times 1$ vector, $\mathbf{y}=(\mathbf{y}_1',\mathbf{y}_2',\ldots,\mathbf{y}_n')',p>n$, which has the density as

$$f_p(\mathbf{y})\propto\phi_p(\mathbf{y};\boldsymbol{\mu},\Sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n\Phi(c_1+c_2\mathbf{1}'\mathbf{y}_i)=\phi_p(\mathbf{y};\boldsymbol{\mu},\Sigma)\Phi_n(c_1+c_2A\mathbf{y}),$$

where $\phi$ and $\Phi$ denote the pdf and cdf of the multivariate or univariate normal distribution. $c_1,c_2$ are constant scalars. $A$ is an $n\times p$ matrix, $A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1,\ldots,1 &  &  & 0\\
 & 1,\ldots,1\\
 &  & \ddots\\
0 &  &  & 1,\ldots,1
\end{array}\right).$

The goal is to calculate the mean and variance of this distribution. [Gupta et al. (2004)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X03001313) have derived them for the case $p=n$ and they seem tedious. I would like to know if there exists a simple solution for my problem. Any clue is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Update: they did discuss the case $p\neq n$ in Section 5 of the paper.